How to change the default spacing for adding new pages to file
When i add a new page to my file, it appears to the right of the last one with a default offset.
I can move it manually to align with my snap-grid, but that sucks, when i have to add a lot of pages for a big bundle.
Is there any way to change that default offset value to already match my grid-size?

Currently (including in the upcoming 1.4 release), the default new page placement is hard-coded and can't be changed.
There doesn't seem to be a feature request for this yet, so you can open an issue on the official bug tracker (instructions).
